# Limit of a sum is the sum of the limits: proof by induction

Tags: calculus, limits, induction

I'm trying to prove that if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f_i(x) = L_i$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots, n$, 
then 
$$\lim_{x\to a} \big(f_1(x)+f_2(x)+ \cdots +f_n(x)\big) = L_1+L_2+ \cdots+L_n$$
I've been asked to prove this result by induction, which I am awfully rusty at.

Could anyone give me a hint/motivation for how I should approach this.

My current attempt has been substituting $n$ in the last line for $(k+1)$ (assuming the line is true for $n=k$) but I just lost myself in the algebra of this. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show the case $n=2$ explicitly. Then the transition $n\to n+1$ goes straight through

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try and brush up on your induction first- but here is a sketch of the proof.

**Base Case:** clearly the statement holds if $n=1$, since this is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to a}f_1(x)=L_1$, which we are given.

**Inductive step** Assume the statement holds for some $n=k\in \mathbb{N}$, that is, if $\{f_1,...,f_k\}$ is any collection of $k$ functions such that $\lim_{x\to a}f_i(x)=L_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k$, then:
$$\lim_{x\to a}[f_1(x)+...+f_k(x)]=L_1+...+L_k. $$

Now suppose we have $k+1$ functions $\{f_1,...,f_{k+1}\}$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}f_i(x)=L_i$ for $1\leq i\leq k+1.$ Then:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to a}[f_1(x)+...+f_k(x)+f_{k+1}]&=\lim_{x\to a}[f_1(x)+...+f_k(x)]+\lim_{x\to a}f_{k+1}(x) \quad (I)\\
&=(L_1+...+L_k)+L_{k+1} \quad (II)\\
&=L_1+...+L_k+L_{k+1}
\end{align}

As desired. Thus by induction we are done.

In the first line $(I)$ I have used that if $f,g$ are two functions such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$, where in this specific case I have used $f:=f_1+...+f_k,\enspace g:=f_{k+1}$. In order to establish $(II)$, I have used that We know the limit of $f(=f_1+...+f_k)$ as $x\to a$ exists and equals $L_1+...+L_k$ by the induction assumption.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Calculus - Proofs of Some Basic Limit Rules](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Proofs_of_Some_Basic_Limit_Rules).
[image: Sum rule for limits]
Note that addition is associative, so we can extend the rule to allow using multiple functions instead of only using two.

I hope it helps !